# How can I restart kafka-manager safely with out kill command?

Tags: apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager

my kafka-manager can't update consumer information and keeps the removed consumer groups list, so i try to restart kafka-manager. (i'm using kafka-manager 1.3.3.22 and kafka 2.12-2.1.1)

but README.md in kafka-manager and /bin/kafka-manager command doesn't appear to provide stop/restart.

is there any way to safely restart or terminate kafka-manager? without 'kill -9 PID' commend

Comment: I don't think there is a provision to restart kafka manager out of the box. I see these open issues: https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK/issues/205 and https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK/issues/562

Comment: thank, your comment!!
Without some safy way. i should run 'kill -9 PID_OF_KAFKA_MANAGER' and  'rm ./kafka-manager-1.3.3.22/RUNNING_PID' and then run kafka-manager with ./kafka-manager-1.3.3.22/bin/kafka-manager
i think it is not safe way....

Comment: Probably you can use docker compose

Comment: current my service is running with VM environment without docker.. (we will plan to transfer it to docker but not now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no restart command out of the box however, you can run Kafka Manager as a service.

---

Firstly, create the service file under `/etc/systemd/system/kafka-manager.service`
and add the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kafka Manager
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/kafka-manager-1.3.3.22/bin/kafka-manager
Type=simple
```

In `/opt/kafka-manager-1.3.3.22/conf/application.conf`:

```
play.crypto.secret="some-secret"
play.http.requestHandler="play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler"
play.application.loader=loader.KafkaManagerLoader
pinned-dispatcher.type="PinnedDispatcher"
pinned-dispatcher.executor="thread-pool-executor"
kafka-manager.zkhosts="my-zookeeper-connection-string"
kafka-manager.base-zk-path="/a-chroot"
```

In `/opt/kafka-manager-1.3.3.22/conf/application.ini`:

```
-Dapplication.home=/opt/kafka-manager-1.3.3.22
-Dpidfile.path=/opt/kafka-manager-1.3.3.22/kafka-manager.pid
-Dhttp.port=8080
```

and finally run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable kafka-manager --now
```

---

**Start the service**

```
systemctl start kafka-manager.service
```

**Stop the service**

```
systemctl stop kafka-manager.service
```

**Restart the service**

```
systemctl restart kafka-manager.service
```